# Connect to WCF WebService on Android / 415 error

Tags: java, android, web-services

I would like to connect to my WCF WebService on Android project. I follow tutorial

http://javatutorialspoint.blogspot.com/2012/02/android-web-service-access-using-ksoap2.html

but I got 415 error. Maybe there is other simply way to connect? Or I should fix something?

> 04-16 10:57:10.675: E/WS(4858): java.io.IOException: HTTP request
>   failed, HTTP status: 415

it's url of my web service (it's local) http://hq.fs.com.pl:8090/fs/Integrator

## Activity

```
package com.example.fs;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class AndroidWSClientActivity extends Activity {

    //private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://ws.android.com/sayHello";
    //private static final String METHOD_NAME = "sayHello";
    //private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://ws.android.com/";
    //private static final String URL = "http://175.157.229.119:8080/AndroidWSTest/services/PrintMsg?wsdl";

    // WS
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IntegratorMethods/GetAddonsTypes";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "GetAddonsTypes";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static final String URL = "http://hq.fs.com:8090/fs/Integrator?wsdl";

    TextView textView;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wsclient_page);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);


    Thread networkThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          try {
             SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);         
             SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
             envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

             HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
             ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
             final  SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
             final String str = response.toString();

             runOnUiThread (new Runnable(){ 
         public void run() {
             textView.setText(str);
               }
           });
          }
         catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("WS", e.toString());
         }
        }
      };
      networkThread.start();
      }
}
```

## Update

I check my connection to WebService with chrome://soaclient/content/webservices.xul and everything looks fine. I've got Operation: GetAddonsTypes and Status: 200 OK.

Comment: I change my Soap version to .VER12 and got 500 error. My WCF service is working on custom Soap 11 version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a Chinese developer,so my English is poor.
I had the same problem,solved it by changing SoapEnvelope.VER12 to SoapEnvelope.VER10.
Problem is solved,but I do not knew why.
My wsdl file is 
xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
so the version should be 12,not 10.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, solved it by changing WsHttpBinding to basicHttpBinding on the endpoint configuration of the WCF Service

Answer (score 0):

this may helps you  make `Request` Like

```
private static final String URL =
"http://give Here Server Ipaddress/AndroidWSTest/services/PrintMsg?wsl";
```

means give current update `ipaddress` 
also make sure your passing

```
(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME)
```

is correct and match with `webServie` `Method name` and `Namespace` also check `Intenet Conncetion` and `webservice` working fine `Server` side or Not

Comment: It's not about wrong URL I think. I said I follow tutorial, but WebService is created with WCF (not Axis2 like in tutorial).